# If I have "ExpiresActive On" in .htaccess, will the changes still be adopted when changes are made by ETags?

Tags: .htaccess

On my website, the pictures always change at midnight. Of course I want that at 0.00: 01 a.m. the change has been made and people see the new images. Does the catch time of one hour works and if so, can I set it to 1 day or even a month?

```
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # | Keep alive |
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
    </ifModule>
    
    # Aktiviert GZIP Komprimierung
     <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
     SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
     </IfModule>
    
     # Browser Caching aktivieren
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 hour
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 hour"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 days"
```

Comment: You are more likely to get answers if you give more detail -- what software are you using, what file is the snippet from, and (if it is relevant) what OS, what browser, etc.?

Comment: _“Does the catch time of one hour works”_ - of course it doesn’t. If I visit your page at 23:57, and you just told my browser, that the image can be cached for one hour … well then my browser has no reason to check if the image was updated, when I do a soft reload of your page at 00:03.

Comment: If your page is dynamically generated, then I would rather go for a longer caching time (1 day), and use what’s called a _cache buster_ on the image URL itself (additional GET parameter), that changes at midnight (so that could f.e. just be the current date in YMD format.)